# How to downsize my scss code?

Tags: html, css, sass

I started writing classes such as:

```
.small-bottom-margin { margin-bottom: $margin; }
.small-top-margin { margin-top: $margin; }
.medium-bottom-margin { margin-bottom: $margin *2; }
.medium-top-margin { margin-top: $margin *2; }
.large-bottom-margin { margin-bottom: $margin *4; }
.large-top-margin { margin-top: $margin *4; }
```

Soon I wanted to be able to specify what happened on different screens, such as (for the small bottom margin example):

```
@media #{$small-only} { .small-bottom-margin-sm { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
@media #{$medium-only} { .small-bottom-margin-md { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
@media #{$large-only} { .small-bottom-margin-lg { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
@media #{$small-up} { .small-bottom-margin-sm-up { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
@media #{$medium-up} { .small-bottom-margin-md-up { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
@media #{$large-up} { .small-bottom-margin-lg-up { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
@media #{$medium-down} { .small-bottom-margin-sm-mp { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
```

... etc for all the margin sizes (medium and large), and for the top margin too.

I find this extremely practical in terms of readability of my html + speed to add margins through my app, which is often a pain when you have a complicated layout, but it seems awfully long to write in my css.

> Is it bad practice to do this?
>   If not, is there some kind of css function that would allow me to automatically generate all this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a matter of your own coding style and taste, in the first place, but for me these classes seem kind of 'unsemantic'.

What if, one day, you decide that it is more practical for those elements to have a `padding` instead of a `margin`. So you just do the following:

```
.small-bottom-margin {
    /* margin-bottom: $margin; */
    padding-bottom: $margin;
}
```

This works, but makes your class name look stupid. Much like a class called `.red-button`. Naming it `.alert-button` would be much more future proof.

I tend to always name classes after what’s their function.

If you want to go that way anyway, you could keep that SCSS more DRY by doing something like this.

```
$breakpoints: (
    'sm': $small-only,
    'md': $medium-only,
    'lg': $large-only,
    'sm-up': $small-up,
    'md-up': $medium-up,
    'lg-up': $large-up,
    'sm-mp': $medium-down
);

$sizeFactors: (
    'small': 1,
    'medium: 2,
    'large: 4
);

$directions: (
    'up',
    'down',
);

@each $breakpointKey, $breakpointValue in $breakpoints {
    @media #{$breakpointValue} {
        @each $sizeFactorKey, $sizeFactorValue in $sizeFactors {
            @each $direction in $directions {
                .#{$sizeFactorKey}-#{$direction}-margin-#{$breakpointKey} {
                    margin-#{$direction}: $margin * $sizeFactorValue; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I called my class .small-bottom-spacing though, instead of margin? This way I describe the function of the class. (In reality if that was better, I would find this a bit silly, as we're playing with words... but curious to know what you think!)

Comment: Generally I agree with what 'iuliu.net' said – you should keep your classes more specific, so that you get a bunch of CSS rules on a single class instead of a whole bunch of classes on a single HTML element. But yes: I find it better to do something like `small-bottom-spacing` at least. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you both say; this seems to be the agreed way. I just don't understand it as, I can have 2 workflows. a) Create all my classes beforehand, and when I need them I just add them to my html. Or b) Create a class for each of my html elements I want to add spacing to, then go in the css, write that class there with its spacing, when most of the time there isn't any other attribute I want to give it. If I want to change that spacing later on, I'll have to find that class in the css rather than just modifying it directly in my html. Is that not a massive waste of time?

Comment: You don’t have to write classes specific to one single element. The difficulty is to aggregate properties in a reasonable and manageable way. I’d ask your question from the other side: If you have 30 headings with `.small-bottom-spacing` and 30 mixed other elements with this class. Later you want to decrease the margin for all of them but the headings. Now you have to go through all your markup, and give the elements something like `.very-very-small-bottom-spacing` instead or go with something like `.small-bottom-spacing:not(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6) { margin-bottom: $margin/2; }`. You know?

Comment: Hm yeah, makes sense. Right, I'll dig in my code and see how I can refactor it. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you that it’s some kind of tempting to do it the way you described, but it ends up in tons of potentially unused CSS. This may be good for prototyping but I would avoid in production. Marking iuliu’s or my answer would be appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through different sizes like this:

```
   $sizes: (
      'sm': $small-only,
      'md': $medium-only,
      'lg': $large-only,
      'sm-up': $small-up,
      'md-up': $medium-up,
      'lg-up': $large-up,
      'sm-mp': $medium-down
    );

    @each $key, $value in $sizes {
      @media #{$value} { .small-bottom-margin-#{$key} { margin-bottom: $margin; }}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have way too many classes. You are basically just replicating all the css properties only for the sake of not using inline styles, which is indeed suboptimal but definitely better than doing something like this.

When you apply a CSS class to an element, it should primarily tell what that specific element **is a *class* of**, not describe what type of visual style it should have applied.

According to [the Google HTML/CSS Style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#CSS_Style_Rules), under *ID and Class Naming* they say that

```
/* Not recommended: presentational */
.button-green {}
.clear {}
```

and should rather have something that would implicitly mean more properties at once, like

```
/* Recommended: specific */
.contact-image {}
.btn-primary {}
.video {}
```

In this way, you avoid having extreme amounts of classes on an element (I guess you have to apply like a minimum of 4-5 of those to get an element look the way you want), and you also add meaning to an element. In HTML, meaning is always good.

Also, assuming that you have cases where your element is not satisfied fully by a class, but is more rather a variation of an existing one, you can either add the differences inline or create variation classes (like `.disabled`, `.big`, `.full-width`) if you think they can appear again in the future.

Comment: isn't .full-width the same concept that .large-bottom-margin though? Or maybe that .large-bottom-spacing, if margin is too literal?

Comment: Depends on your app really. I actually have a type of button that can be either a fixed with, a dynamic with, or a full width (of the parent). This is what the designer came up with, so they are like three variations of the same class. It just happens for one of them to be close to your case.